# How to restrict interrupt signal to just the child process?

Tags: linux, signals, tail, trap, interrupt

I have a bunch of log files and I want to do a `tail -f` on them in a loop such that when I press Ctrl-C, the current `tail -f` gets killed and I proceed to the next log file:

```
for log in *.log; do
    printf '%s\n' "Tailing log '$log'; press Ctrl-C to skip to the next"
    tail -f "$log"
done
```

The issue is that pressing Ctrl-C kills the loop itself.  How can I restrict the interrupt signal to just the child process, `tail` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
trap ":" SIGINT
```

before the loop. This makes the shell ignore the signal. But just in the sense that it executes a dummy command, not "ignore" in the signal handler sense.

Because the shell process does not block this signal (from the kernel perspective) it gets through to its child processes (like `tail` in this example).

Comment: This worked, thanks!  Do you want to add how this works actually?

Comment: Also, would this work I was running a built-in command instead of an external command like `tail`?

Comment: @codeforester With the exception of `wait` built-in commands should finish before the shell reacts to the signal. But with few exceptions the built-in commands are executed so quickly that you would not notice anyway.